# Duda bucle Json

Tags: json, jsonp

Tengo un archivo Json de películas y es bastante largo para lo que yo lo quiero realmente pero ese no es el caso, el problema de que sea tan largo es que quiero añadirle varios campos mas a cada película y soy bastante novato a la hora de trabajar sobre estos tipos de ficheros (En mi caso lo trabajo con Python) y quiero crear un bucle para ir añadiendo los datos a todas las películas, se que es bastante simple seguramente pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo por mas que lo intente.

El formato del archivo json es el siguiente:

```
[
{
    "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
    "rank": "1",
    "id": "tt0111161"
},
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "rank": "2",
    "id": "tt0068646"
},
{
    "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
    "rank": "3",
    "id": "tt0071562"
},
{
    "title": "Pulp Fiction",
    "rank": "4",
    "id": "tt0110912"
},
{
    "title": "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly",
    "rank": "5",
    "id": "tt0060196"
]
```

He probado con varios formatos del for pero no hay manera de sacarlo, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar un poco y iluminarme con la idea, porque se modificar los datos pero no añadir nuevos, en este caso quiero añadir debajo de id otro campo que se llame Oscars, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar!

Un saludo!

Comment: Podrías crear otro json tomando los datos del que ya tenés y agregando los nuevos campos. Sería crear un nuevo json, dentro de un bucle for recorrer el json que ya tenés, y por cada elemento crear uno nuevo tomando los datos que ya tenés más los nuevos, e insertar ese nuevo elemento en el json que creaste.

Answer (score 1):

estas en lo correcto con tu idea del ciclo for si ya tienes definido de donde te vas a traer tus nuevas peliculas, y mas por que tienes un arreglo de objetos.
Para agregar un nuevo elemento solo tienes que utilizar la funcion push() que traen los arreglos de JS

```
//tus peliculas
var movies = [
{
    "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
    "rank": "1",
    "id": "tt0111161"
},
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "rank": "2",
    "id": "tt0068646"
},
{
    "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
    "rank": "3",
    "id": "tt0071562"
}
]

//tus nuevas peliculas
var newMovies = [
{
    "title": "Pulp Fiction",
    "rank": "4",
    "id": "tt0110912"
},
{
    "title": "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly",
    "rank": "5",
    "id": "tt0060196"
}
]
```

y con push() de nuevas peliculas, puedes agregar elementos a tu lista

```
newMovies.forEach(function(value){
   movies.push(value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué te parece esta forma?

```
jsonEntrada = [
{
    "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
    "rank": "1",
    "id": "tt0111161"
},
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "rank": "2",
    "id": "tt0068646"
},
{
    "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
    "rank": "3",
    "id": "tt0071562"
},
{
    "title": "Pulp Fiction",
    "rank": "4",
    "id": "tt0110912"
},
{
    "title": "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly",
    "rank": "5",
    "id": "tt0060196"
}
]

jsonSalida = list()

for pelicula in jsonEntrada:
    pelicula ['rating'] = 5
    jsonSalida.append(pelicula)

print(jsonSalida)
```

Cambiar el JSON que tienes es tan sencillo como tratarlo como un diccionario. En este ejemplo añadimos un rating fijo a todas las películas del json.

Si quisieramos iterar sobre los valores de cada película, solo habría que obtener los items de cada una:

```
for pelicula in jsonEntrada:
    for k,v in pelicula.items():
        print(k,'->',v)
```

Por último recuerda que **jsonEntrada** es una lista de **diccionarios**.